# Quando o Acordo Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa será oficialmente adotado por todos países-membros?

Tags: acordo-ortográfico

De acordo com [esta reportagem](http://agenciabrasil.ebc.com.br/geral/noticia/2016-01/novo-acordo-ortografico-e-obrigatorio-partir-de-hoje) que foi referenciada [neste post do meta](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215/novo-acordo-ortogr%C3%A1fico-obrigat%C3%B3rio-em-2016-no-brasil), o Brasil adotou oficialmente as alterações decorrente do novo Acordo Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa no dia 1º de Janeiro de 2016. Ainda, segundo esta fonte, dos 8 países-membros (Brasil, Portugal, Cabo Verde, Angola, Moçambique, Guiné-Bissau, São Tomé e Príncipe e Timor-Leste), apenas os 3 primeiros (Brasil, Portugal e Cabo Verde) já adotaram oficialmente o Acordo.

Os outros 5 países já possuem data oficial para adoção do Acordo? Caso positivo, em que data poderemos dizer que a Língua Portuguesa estará pretensamente unificada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Wikipedia tem [aqui uma tabela](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acordo_Ortogr%C3%A1fico_de_1990#Resumo_da_situa.C3.A7.C3.A3o_nos_pa.C3.ADses_e_regi.C3.B5es_lus.C3.B3fonos) que representa a situação atual nos países em que português é língua oficial. Em suma, o Acordo está em vigor em três países (Brasil, Cabo Verde e Portugal), ratificado mas não implementado na maioria dos restantes e nem sequer ratificado em [Angola](https://iilp.wordpress.com/2015/09/25/ministro-brasileiro-pede-ratificacao-do-novo-acordo-ortografico-por-angola-2/) ou Moçambique (onde aparentemente foi aprovado pelo governo em 2012 mas não pelo parlamento).

Já agora, nunca foi objetivo do acordo «unificar a Língua Portuguesa» (que de qualquer forma não é uma entidade una nem dentro dos próprios países), apenas aproximar a ortografia nos vários países.

Comment: Talvez a intenção do Acordo não seja unificar _toda_ a língua portuguesa, mas apenas sua ortografia. O próprio link que citaste diz em seu início: O Acordo Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa de 1990 é um tratado internacional firmado em 1990 com o objetivo de criar uma _ortografia unificada_ para o português, a ser usada por todos os países de língua oficial portuguesa.